# How do I make a log plot where the plot is logarithmic in the distance from the X-Axis (including negative values)?

Tags: plotting, graphics

For example, if I were to do a plot of `Sin[x]`, I would get what looks like a Log plot of `Sin[x]`, with another log plot of `-Sin[x]` that has been flipped upside down and placed underneath the first one, in this way, the plot is logarithmic in distance from the x-axis, and can show both positive and negative values.

Comment: You're aware of the ambiguity that appears with plotting, say, `2Sin[x]` in this style?

Comment: @RahulNarain 2Sin[x] should be slightly larger in distance from the x-axis at its peak than Sin[x], right?

Comment: I was thinking of [what happens with belisarius's method](http://i.stack.imgur.com/boIgQ.png) when I wrote that comment.

Comment: Andrew, I keep meaning to return to this question to add logarithmic ticks to the `logify` method in my answer.  If I don't do this in the next 48 hours please leave a comment to remind me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard:  Since you asked, and I would love for the answer, this is your 48 hour reminder (give or take).  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, still busy today, but I'll try to make it soon!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I interpret this question quite differently from the other responders.

> I would get what looks like a Log plot of Sin[x], with another log plot of -Sin[x] that has been flipped upside down and placed underneath the first one.

We can do that rather literally like this:

```
p1 = LogPlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 15}];
p2 = LogPlot[-Sin[x], {x, 0, 15}];

pivot = Last[AxesOrigin /. Options[p2]];

Show[
 p1,
 MapAt[Scale[#, {1, -1}, {0, pivot}] &, p2, 1],
 PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is not an ideal method however and I shall be working on a better one.

---

Here is a second method based on manipulating the output of `LogPlot`.  If the logarithmic ticks are not required this is overly complicated.  The Red/Blue style is added only for illustration.

```
p = LogPlot[{Sin[x], -Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 15}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}];

pivot = Last[AxesOrigin /. Options@p];

MapAt[# /. Line[x__] :> Line[{#, 2 pivot - #2} & @@@ x] &, p, {1, 1, 4}] /. {
  (Ticks -> {xdat_, ydat_}) :>
   Ticks -> {xdat, Join[ydat, {2 pivot - #, ##2} & @@@ ydat]},
  (PlotRange -> {x_, {y_, Y_}}) :> PlotRange -> {x, {2 y, Y}}
 }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

If $y$ ticks are unimportant you might use something like this:

```
logify[off_][x_?Positive] := Max[0, (off + Re@Log@x)/off]
logify[off_][x_?Negative] := Min[0, (off + Re@Log@x)/-off]
```

The parameter `off` is a scaling function.  Example of use:

```
Plot[
 logify[1] /@ {Sin@x, Cos@x, E Sin[x], E^2 Sin[x]},
 {x, 0, 15},
 Axes -> {True, False},
 Evaluated -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As above but with `logify[5]`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Update

I am four years overdue on this, but now with ticks by leveraging [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html), which unofficially works in `Plot` in *Mathematica* 10 but may not in earlier editions.

```
logify[off_][a_List] := logify[off] /@ a
logify[off_][x_?Positive] := Max[0, (off + Re@Log@x)/off]
logify[off_][x_?Negative] := Min[0, (off + Re@Log@x)/-off]

invlog[off_][a_List] := invlog[off] /@ a
invlog[off_][x_?Positive] :=  Exp[ x*off - off]
invlog[off_][x_?Negative] := -Exp[-x*off - off]
```

Application:

```
Plot[
 {Sin@x, Cos@x, E Sin[x], E^2 Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 15},
 ScalingFunctions -> {logify[2], invlog[2]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting interpretation. I think a drawing in the question would be much better than wording it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It seems you can avoid the jump at y=0 via say , `p = LogPlot[{Sin[x], -Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 15}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
   PlotRange -> {0.001, 1}];`

Comment: On the other hand, `p = LogPlot[{Sin[x], -Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 15}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> {0.001, 10}];` only extends the red axis (so to speak).

Comment: @Verde: Yes, this is actually the interpretation I was looking for, but apparently I wasn't clear...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard As usual, you come through!  With bonus points because I can use your answer to do the same thing with ListLogPlot, which was what I originally wanted.

Comment: Your `update` "pinks" after multiple evaluations of the Plot :(

Comment: @user6014 In version 10.1 I could not reproduce the problem you describe.  Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[{Sin@x, Sign@Sin@x Log@Abs@Sin@x}, {x, 0, 10 Pi}, Exclusions -> {(Sin@x == 0)}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Just a nice plot with `Log@Sin@x`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Framed@Plot[{Sign@Sin@x Log@Abs@Sin@x, Log@Tan[x + Pi], -Log@Tan[x - Pi/2]}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
  Exclusions -> {(Sin@x == 0)}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-5, 5}}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {3}, 1 -> {2}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}, {Thick, Red}}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Gray, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

```
f[x_] := Which[Sin[x] > 0, Log[Sin[x]], Sin[x] < 0, -Log[-Sin[x]]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Since this is a mathematical function, `Piecewise` would be more appropriate than `Which`. Alternately, you can ditch the piecewise definitions and use `Sign@# Log@Abs@# &@Sin[x]` instead :)