# Switch from logarithmic to linear scaling partway along a plot's axis

Tags: plotting, customization, logarithmic-scale

In the 2015 Planck satellite results, they give the latest plot of the temperature power spectrum of the cosmic microwave background, which I show below. (I am only interested in the main plot; you can ignore the residuals at the bottom.)

Notice that there is a dotted vertical line at $\ell=30$, and the *x*-axis to the right of that line is linear while to the left it is logarithmic.

How close of an approximation to this effect can I create in Mathematica?

[image: Planck 2015 temperature power spectrum]

Comment: I have this solved in a package I wrote for my needs. It involves plotting `f[g[x]]` instead of `f[x]` where `g` is a `Piecewise` function that grows logarithmically in one range of `x` and then linearly in the next. Then you need to manually specify the ticks such that the positions are distorted as the inverse function of `g`. Once I get to work tomorrow I can post a full answer if someone doesn't come up with one before that.

Comment: Related: [(6877)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6877/121),
[(8241)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8241/121),
[(13373)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13373/121)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I look forward to your answer.  I think that is similar in concept to what I did here: [(78708)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78708/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it's actually very simple when using the `TickPostTransformation` option in `CustomTicks`. I'll see if I have anything useful on my laptop right now.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, that a very interesting thing with `ScalingFunctions` you did in your solution. So far, though, they only work with a limited set of plotting functions, right?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Yes, and some of them are not officially supported so the functionality may change or disappear.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, here's a very brief toy example while I don't have access to my desktop computer at work.

It's easy enough to figure out, that a `LogPlot` of `f` is basically the plot of `Log[f[x]]`. And A `LogLinearPlot` is the plot of `f[Exp[x]]`. But we can extend this to arbitrary scalings of the axes.

I start with defining a piecewise function which maps x values between 0 and 1 to the interval from 1 to 10 logarithmically and x values between 1 and 2 to the interval 10 to 100 linearly, as well as the inverse of that.

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{10^x, 0 <= x < 1},
                    {Rescale[x, {1, 2}, {10, 100}], x >= 1}}]
inverseg[x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Log[10, x], 1 <= x < 10},
            {Rescale[x, {10, 100}, {1, 2}], x >= 10}}]
```

Then if you have the [`CustomTicks` package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/):

```
Needs["CustomTicks`"];
ticks = LinTicks[1, 10, TickPostTransformation -> inverseg]~Join~
   LinTicks[10, 100, TickPostTransformation -> inverseg];
```

If you don't have it:

```
ticks = {N@inverseg@#, 
     ToString@#, {0.01, 0}, {}} & /@ (Range[2, 10, 2]~Join~
     Range[20, 100, 20]);
```

Finally (I show `Sin[x]` in this toy example):

```
Plot[Sin[g[x]], {x, 0, 2}, Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}]
```

[image: Scaled ticks]

Note, how according to the `x-y` coordinates taken from the axes labels this is just the regular Sin[x] function, but everything is distorted such, that we see the desired log scaling before 10 and linear scaling after.

This plot was generated without using the `CustomTicks` package, hence lazy and without minor ticks. I'll go into more details tomorrow.

**Update 05.05.15**

Writing out these piecewise functions by hand is tedious. I've automated this.

Firstly, a function I called `MapLog`, though `logRescale` may have been more appropriate. Although, unlike `Rescale[x, {x1, x2}, {y1 y2}]` where simply swapping the 2nd and 3rd argument gives you the inverse function, with a logarithmic/exponential mapping it's a bit less straightforward.

```
MapLog[{x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_}, type_String: "Direct"] :=
    Which[
        type == "Direct", (Log[(x2/x1)^(1/(y2 - y1)), #1/x1] + y1 &),
        type == "Inverse", (x1 (x2/x1)^((#1 - y1)/(y2 - y1)) &)]
```

The default `"Direct"` form take the interval `{x1, x2}` and maps it to the interval `{y1, y2}` logarithmically.

```
Plot[MapLog[{1, 10, 0, 1}][x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image: MapLog Direct]

```
MapLog[{1,10,0,1}, "Inverse"]
```

will naturally give the inverse of such an operation.

Next comes the main function `AxisBreaks`, which handles the construction of the direct and inverse transformation functions for the ticks and coordinates.

```
Options[AxisBreaks] = {Output -> "Direct"};
AxisBreaks[specs :
             PatternSequence[{{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _String : "Lin"} ..}],
           opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    Module[{
        fullspecs = (If[Length[#] == 3, Join[#, {"Lin"}], #, #] &) /@ specs,
        ranges2 = Accumulate[specs[[All, 3]]],
        ranges1 = Accumulate[specs[[All, 3]]] - specs[[All, 3]],
        expspecs, dirfunc, invfunc, output
        },
    expspecs = 
     Transpose@{fullspecs[[All, 1]], fullspecs[[All, 2]], ranges1, ranges2, fullspecs[[All, 4]]};

    If[OptionValue[Output] == "Direct",
       dirfunc[x_] :=
       Piecewise[Table[
        {Which[j[[5]] == "Lin", Rescale[x, j[[1 ;; 2]], j[[3 ;; 4]]],
               j[[5]] == "Log", MapLog[j[[1 ;; 4]], "Direct"][x]], 
         j[[1]] <= x <= j[[2]]}, {j, expspecs}]];];

    If[OptionValue[Output] == "Inverse",
       invfunc[x_] := 
       Piecewise[Table[
        {Which[j[[5]] == "Lin", Rescale[x, j[[3 ;; 4]], j[[1 ;; 2]]],
               j[[5]] == "Log", MapLog[j[[1 ;; 4]], "Inverse"][x]], 
         j[[3]] <= x <= j[[4]]}, {j, expspecs}]];];

    Which[OptionValue[Output] == "Direct", output = dirfunc;,
          OptionValue[Output] == "Inverse", output = invfunc;];
    output
    ]
```

Usage is as follows:

```
specs = {{1, 30, 1, "Log"}, {30, 500, 4}};
dg = AxisBreaks[specs];
ig = AxisBreaks[specs, Output -> "Inverse"];
```

Which means in plain English "give me a function, that maps the interval `{1, 30}` logarithmically to 1 part of the plot and the interval `{30, 500}` to 4 parts of the plot (specifically, to `{0, 1}` and `{1, 5}`, respectively. Also give me the inverse function of this."

Then a little helper to generate the ticks:

```
makeTicks[func_, major_List, minor_List: {}] := 
({func@#, ToString@#, {0.01, 0}, {}} & /@ major) ~Join~ 
({func@#, "", {0.005, 0}, {}} & /@ minor);
```

Usage:

```
major = {2, 10, 30}~Join~Range[100, 500, 100]; (* can't be bothered to make minor ticks *)
ticks = makeTicks[dg, major];
```

Basically give the transformation function as the first argument, the list of major ticks as the second, minor ticks are an optional third argument.

Now plot `f[x]`, replacing as `f[ig[x]]` (`ig` is the inverse transformation), and if you want to plot between `x1` and `x2`, you now need to substitute `dg[x1]` and `dg[x2]` (`dg` is the direct transformation).

```
Plot[Sin[15/Sqrt[ig@x]], {x, dg[1], dg[500]}, 
 Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Plot]

**Neat examples**

This goes beyond the scope of the OP, but `AxisBreaks` can do a lot more, that I'd like to showcase.

`LogLinearPlot` for negative values? Negative and positive values? No problem.

```
specs = {{-1000, -5, 2, "Log"}, {-5, 5, 1}, {5, 1000, 2, "Log"}};
dg = AxisBreaks[specs];
ig = AxisBreaks[specs, Output -> "Inverse"];
ticks = 
 makeTicks[dg,
  {-1000, -300, -100, -30, -10, 10, 30, 100, 300, 1000}~Join~Range[-4, 4, 2]];
Plot[Log[1 + y^2] /. y -> ig[x], {x, dg[-1000], dg[1000]}, 
 Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> {dg[0], 0}]
```

[image: LogLinear]

[Generating a broken or snipped axis?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8241/generating-a-broken-or-snipped-axis-in-listplot)

The graphical part aside (that's straighforward with `Epilog`), how to show two datasets like

```
data1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 30];
data2 = RandomReal[{1000, 1001}, 30];
```

on one graph? Simple, the intervals need not be continuous, just monotonically increasing and log mapping mustn't cross zero.

```
specs = {{0, 1.1, 1}, {999.9, 1001.1, 1}};
dg = AxisBreaks[specs];
ig = AxisBreaks[specs, Output -> "Inverse"];
ticks = makeTicks[dg, Range[0, 1, .2]~Join~Range[1000, 1001, .2]];
ListPlot[{dg /@ data1, dg /@ data2}, Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image: Different ranges]

Note, that as it is now the y-axis being rescaled, I apply the direct transformation to the data (`dg`, not `ig`), and I actually don't need the inverse. Also I slightly padded the intervals being remapped, as they aren't continuous.

Both axes at the same time. Say we have four datasets which occupy rather different ranges (smallX, smallY), (smallX, bigY), (bigX, bigY), (bigX, smallY), although with some limitations.

```
data1 = Transpose@{Range[1, 10], 
    Range[.5, 5, .5] + RandomReal[{0, 0.3}, 10]};
data2 = Transpose@{Range[1000, 1100, 10], 
    Range[5, 0, -.5] + RandomReal[{0, 0.3}, 11]};
data3 = Transpose@{Range[1000, 1100, 10], 
    Range[500, 1500, 100] + RandomReal[{0, 10}, 11]};
data4 = Transpose@{Range[1, 10], 
    Range[1500, 600, -100] + RandomReal[{0, 10}, 10]};
specsx = {{0, 11, 1}, {990, 1110, 1}};
specsy = {{0, 6, 1}, {500, 1600, 1}};
dgx = AxisBreaks[specsx];
dgy = AxisBreaks[specsy];
ticksx = makeTicks[dgx, Range[1, 10]~Join~Range[1000, 1100, 20]];
ticksy = makeTicks[dgy, Range[1, 5]~Join~Range[500, 1500, 200]];
ListPlot[Map[{dgx[#[[1]]], dgy[#[[2]]]} &, {data1, data2, data3, 
   data4}, {2}], Ticks -> {ticksx, ticksy}]
```

[image: Four sets]

In the case of ListPlot where data are given as x-y pairs, we apply the direct transform to the x coordinate too. The inverse is again not needed.

Feel free to suggest further examples.

**Bonus - reproduction of the graph in OP**

Simply load the definitions of `AxisBreaks` and `MapLog` and run below code to get

```
specs = {{2, 30, 2, "Log"}, {30, 2500, 4}};
dg = AxisBreaks[specs, Output -> "Direct"];
ig = AxisBreaks[specs, Output -> "Inverse"];
makeTicks[func_, major_List, 
   minor_List: {}] := ({func@#, ToString@#, {0.02, 0}, {}} & /@ 
     major)~Join~({func@#, "", {0.01, 0}, {}} & /@ minor);
major = {2, 10, 30}~Join~Range[500, 2500, 500];
minor = Range[3, 9]~Join~{20}~Join~Range[100, 2400, 100];
ticks = makeTicks[dg, major, minor];
func[x_] := 
 Total@Thread[((#2 #3 x^2)/(#3^2 x^2 + (-x^2 + #1^2)^2) &)
     [{2, 250, 600, 800, 1500}, {2, 100, 40, 40, 40}, {30, 200, 200, 200, 1000}]]
 Plot[10^4 func[ig[x]], {x, dg[2], dg[2500]}, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 ImageSize -> 600, BaseStyle -> 16, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {ticks, Automatic}, 
 Epilog -> {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{dg[30], -200}, {dg[30], 5500}}]}]
```

[image: Planck data]

Comment: similarly you can  do `ParametricPlot[{inverseg[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 1, 100}, ..` (perhaps preferable  for readability sake )

Comment: Also true, but the salt and pepper lies in modifying the ticks. But you're right, that that way you can actually specify the true range for x. Similarly, for plot there's always the option of `{x, inverseg[1], inverseg[100]}`

Comment: Okay. So, in order to understand what you are doing here, I am trying to generalize this to the case where I want my plot range to go from `a` to `c`, switching from logarithmic to linear at an intermediate value `b`. (In your example, `a=1`, `b=10`, and `c=100`.) I have successfully rewritten the first part: `g[x_] := Piecewise[{{10^x, Log10[a] <= x < Log10[b]}, {Rescale[x, {Log10[b], Log10[c]}, {b, c}], x >= Log10[b]}}]` and `inverseg[x_] := Piecewise[{{Log10[x], a <= x < b}, {Rescale[x, {b, c}, {Log10[b], Log10[c]}], x >= Log10[b]}}]`. But I don't know what's going on in the `ticks =` line.

Comment: (Your second option—I don't have the CustomTicks package on hand.)

Comment: Well, if everything's properly defined, you simply need to adjust the `Range[...]` properly. In my example I figured I want a major tick in steps of 2 at the log-scale part and in steps of 20 at the linear scale part and the x-values there were ranging from 1 to 10 and 10 to 100, respectively. So I wrote `Range[2,10,2]` and `Range[20,100,20]`. You want something along the lines of `Range[a,b,stepsize1]` and `Range[b,c,stepsize2]`, then fine-tune according to your plot.

Comment: What is the `{0.01, 0}` part doing?

Comment: These are tick length specifications. I'd refer you to the documentation for `Ticks` which explains in detail, how ticks are specified and such. If you're comfortable with shorthand notations in Mathematica, such as `&/@` which I used a lot of, then after studying the docs for the `Ticks` option you should have no problem understanding what's going on in my `ticks = ...` assignment.

Comment: Happy 1K rep! :D

Comment: Thanks! It feels undeserved, in lieu of an update the Wizard's answer is so much cleaner :-)

Comment: 1K is based on a lot more than a single answer.  Besides we've all received undeserved upvotes.  It's part of the SE model. ;P  Also, see this: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/987/im-getting-close-to-5000-points-on-mathematica-stack-exchange/

Comment: As promised, the updated and improved code in the edit.

Comment: And I threw in an attempt to reproduce your plot. I'm almost certain you can get arbitrarily close, as that plot looks like it's also been made in Mathematica.

Comment: Wow, you leave things unattended for a few hours and they just spiral out of control! Thanks for all the additional work. Not particularly related to the topic at hand, but I'm very curious regarding the process by which you constructed `func` in your attempt to reproduce my plot.

Comment: `func` is simply a sum of five lorentzians - terms with the following dependence on frequency: `Im[f/(f0^2-f^2-I g f)]`. As this seems to be a spectrum of some sort, I figured it's an appropriate term. I constructed a pure function for the above expression and threaded it over a list of 5 frequencies (for the peak position), 5 amplitudes, 5 widths (that's the `g`). Apologies though, the `func` in my code has only 3 lorentzians, but the plot was generated with 5. Will update in a moment.

Comment: Wonderful answer.  I won't be disappointed if I lose the Accept to this. :-)

Comment: I feel bad that I can't upvote more than once. This looks all fantastic!

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the positive response. There is just one thing I still can't fully automate and it is the generation of "nice" tick positions, which I have so far done manually in every example. In my own package it *is* partially automated with some help from `CustomTicks` (and as it it's an external package, I didn't include code for it here), but it works properly only for the linear sections and can cause ugliness where two intervals meet.

Comment: Your update is of course amazing, but thanks also for your initial response, which was highly pedagogical and which in some ways I like even better for its straightforwardness. (Of course, I *say* that, but you can still be sure the code I'm actually using right now is the update!)

Comment: Thanks for the accept! For sure, I decided to keep the initial response up at the top, as it really is the underlying explanation of how this is done (or rather, how my approach works).

Answer (score 21):

If you are comfortable using undocumented and unsupported functionality we can do this with a [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) option as I did for [ListLogLinearPlot for the whole real numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78524/121).

```
(* listability *)
(self :    fn[off_, scale_])[x_List] := self /@ x
(self : invfn[off_, scale_])[x_List] := self /@ x

fn[off_, scale_][x_?NumericQ] :=
  If[x < off, Log[x], x/scale + (Log[off] - off/scale)]

invfn[off_, scale_][x_?NumericQ] := 
  If[x < Log[off], Exp[x], off + x scale - scale Log[off]]

splitlog[n_, scale_: 10] := {fn[n, scale], invfn[n, scale]}
```

To use it:

```
Plot[Sin[15/x], {x, 1, 50},
 PlotRange -> All,
 ScalingFunctions -> {splitlog[9], None},
 GridLines -> {{9}}
]
```

[image]

The first parameter is the *x* point at which to switch from log to linear.  The second (optional) parameter of `splitlog` controls relative scale of the two halves of the plot:

```
Table[
  Plot[Sin[15/x], {x, 1, 50},
    PlotRange -> All,
    ScalingFunctions -> {splitlog[point, scale], None},
    GridLines -> {{point}},
    ImageSize -> 180
  ],
  {point, {3, 15, 35}},
  {scale, {2, 10, 30}}
] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

Comment: That is neat! So what's up with the ticks and labels? M seems to be a bit arbitrary in generating them and it seems to only be dependent on `scale`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I agree the generation seems a bit random but it is likely a rather complex problem to handle *generally*.  You can use one of the tools from [(1742)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/121) to peer at the definitions of ``Charting`ScaledTicks``, ``Charting`FindTicks``, ``Charting`FindLogTicks`` etc. to see the process.  Ultimately manual generation may be needed for the best visual result.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is pure gold. When I was fiddling around, trying to build custom tick functions, these would always come up in error messages...

Comment: In Mathematica 9, I don't see quite the same behavior. In particular, I have to draw the GridLine at `Log[9]` rather than just `9` for it to appear at the place labeled 9 in the plot.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the section you labeled `(* listability *)` doing? In particular, how does it differ from `SetAttributes[{fn, invfn}, Listable]`?

Comment: @thecommexokid regarding grid line at `Log[9]` that is indication of further development of this function which is encouraging, but also indication that one cannot expect it to remain unchanged.  Because I chose SubValues notation for `fn` I cannot use `Listable` itself as that would only thread over `off` and `scale` rather than `x_List`; this is my workaround.